# Webcam recording software for Windows

Tags: windows, video, webcam, video-recording

Can anyone recommend software that will allow you to record video from a webcam?

***Requirements:***

- Windows 7 compatible
- Saves the video in a common video format, such as AVI, MPEG, MP4, etc.
- Saves audio with the video
- Works with a local webcam (not an IP webcam)

***Preferences:***

- Portable software (no installer)
- Gratis

***What I've Tried:***

- VLC: Audio and video were not synced together properly
- VirtualDUB: Audio and video were not synced together properly

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TechSmith Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html):

- non-free, non-portable
- can record the webcam, screen, audio output to the speakers, and audio input (e.g., microphone)
- I've never had any sync issues between audio and video
- easy-to-use GUI
- works with Windows 7
- Saves the video in a common video format, such as AVI, MPEG, MP4, etc.
- Saves audio with the video
- many choices of recording quality and formats / compression vs quality vs resolution

[image]

Comment: Thanks Franck!  Quality answer.  Not sure if I'll bite given the high cost (and expensive upgrades), but definitely a quality answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[CamStudio Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/camstudio_portable) should be able to do what you want.  It is gratis and the version linked is portable as well.  I have used it primarily for screen recordings, such as capturing a presentation.  Depending on the configuration of the hardware and the webcam, it should do what you need.  On occasion, the audio and video may not sync, but it can be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought CamStudio was only for screen recordings, not webcam recordings, but I will have to take another looksee.

Comment: I don't have a webcam configured on my desktop, so have not tested this.  You may be right, but my thinking was that the webcam could stream to a window and that the window could be recorded with CamStudio.  It may also be possible to identify the webcam as the video source and have it recorded that way.  HTH

Comment: The camstudio.org website mentions the following for webcams: "unique Video Annotation feature you can even personalise your videos by including a webcam movie of yourself "picture-in-picture" over your desktop."  Selecting Video Annotations brings up a second window.  Rt-Clicking that gives an option of Video Source.  In my case, w/o a webcam, the only source is screen capture.  I expect a webcam would be selectable there.